# How do i add `name` to a `redirect` URL in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

Here is my router setup from the Vue project

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      redirect: "/dashboard",
    },
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      name: "dashboard-page",
      component: () => import("@/views/Pages/AppDashboard.vue"),
    },
    {
      path: "/customer/",
      name: "customer-page",
      component: () => import("@/views/Pages/CustomerDashboard.vue"),
      children: [
        {
          path: "",
          redirect: "/customer/list",
        },
        {
          path: "list",
          name: "customer-list",
          component: () =>
            import("@/views/Pages/SubPages/Customers/CustomerTable.vue"),
        },
        {
          path: "add",
          name: "add-customer",
          component: () =>
            import("@/views/Pages/SubPages/Customers/CustomerForm.vue"),
          props: { type: "New" },
        },
        {
          path: ": id",
          name: "edit-customer",
          component: () =>
            import("@/views/Pages/SubPages/Customers/CustomerForm.vue"),
          props: { type: "Edit" },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});

export default router;
```

So whenever I don't add a name to the redirect URL in children of `customer` I get the following dev-warning

```
[Vue Router warn]: The route named "customer-page" has a child without a name and an empty path. Using that name won't render the empty path child so you probably want to move the name to the child instead. If this is intentional, add a name to the child route to remove the warning.
```

However, after I add `name: default-redirect` to that child, all children components disappear and I get a blank output in the `router-view` area.

All I am trying to do here is that whenever anyone lands on just `/customer` the page should redirect to `/customer/list`.

Is this a Bug OR am I doing something wrong here?

Here is the Link to [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/route-params-vue-router-4-examples-forked-rkjh4n?file=/src/components/customer/listView.vue) with the minimum required code that will give the same exact error when you try to run in chrome. Try adding/removing the `name:default-redirect` in `/customer` route

Comment: Is it working with named redirect eg. redirect: { name: "customer-page" }

Comment: @Emil No, it's not, I even tried the `redirect: to=>{return {path: '/customer list'} }` and `redirect: to=>{ return {name: 'customer-list'} }` but the same error

Comment: try set name for `path: ''` if not working please post minimal reproduction example or vue-router version

Comment: @TachibanaShin the whole warning occurs when I try to set a name for the `path: ''` In the question itself I have mentioned my actual router code, you can reproduce the error on any given router just by specifying the child routes in any project and insert `{path:'',name:'some-name',redirect:'some-child-link'}` as I have mentioned for `/customer/`

Comment: you can create examples on codesandbox or stackbliz not many? people (me included) don't want to create reproducible examples for other people's problems

Comment: I added a sandbox link in the question as an edit. hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally after a long troubleshooting i found what i was doing wrong
all i had to do was move the `name: "customer-page",` from the parent to the child

so what was expected was something like this

```
{
      path: "/customer/",
      component: () => import("@/views/Pages/CustomerDashboard.vue"),
      children: [
        {
          path: "",
          name: "customer-page",
          redirect: "/customer/list",
        },
        {
          path: "list",
          name: "customer-list",
          component: () =>
            import("@/views/Pages/SubPages/Customers/CustomerTable.vue"),
        },
        {
          path: "add",
          name: "add-customer",
          component: () =>
            import("@/views/Pages/SubPages/Customers/CustomerForm.vue"),
          props: { type: "New" },
        },
        {
          path: ": id",
          name: "edit-customer",
          component: () =>
            import("@/views/Pages/SubPages/Customers/CustomerForm.vue"),
          props: { type: "Edit" },
        },
      ],
    },
```

All i had to do was move the name prop from the root

```
      path: "/customer/",
      component: () => import("@/views/Pages/CustomerDashboard.vue"),
```

to the empty path redirection

```
        {
          path: "",
          name: "customer-page",
          redirect: "/customer/list",
        },
```